# Nested Perform Loops in COBOL?

Tags: cobol, gnucobol, cobol85

Why can I not do this nested perform loop in COBOL?

If I put END-PERFORM. in any line sooner than where I have the last one just before EXIT PROGRAM - it works. But I need the program to display the INPUT C value every time. in the outer perform loop. Its driving me nuts.

```
PROCEDURE DIVISION USING INPUTC CIPHER.
COMPUTE CIPHERMAX = CIPHER.
MULTIPLY -1 BY CIPHER
---> PERFORM VARYING CIPHER FROM 0 BY 1
UNTIL CIPHERMAX = CIPHER
    DISPLAY 'This is loop number: ' CIPHER
    INSPECT INPUTC CONVERTING
    "avcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz" to "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"
    COMPUTE CONVERTNUM = FUNCTION MOD (CIPHER, 26)
    INSPECT FUNCTION REVERSE(INPUTC) TALLYING LENGTHNUM FOR LEADING SPACES
    COMPUTE LENGTHNUM = LENGTH OF CIPHER - LENGTHNUM

 ---> PERFORM UNTIL SENTRY = LENGTHNUM

            IF ((FUNCTION ORD(INPUTC(SENTRY:1)) + CONVERTNUM) > (FUNCTION ORD('Z')))
             MOVE FUNCTION CHAR((FUNCTION ORD(INPUTC(SENTRY:1)) + CONVERTNUM) - 26) TO RECHAR
              ELSE
             MOVE FUNCTION CHAR(FUNCTION ORD(INPUTC(SENTRY:1)) + CONVERTNUM) TO RECHAR
             END-IF  
              IF (((FUNCTION ORD(INPUTC(SENTRY:1))) >= (FUNCTION ORD('A'))) AND 
             ((FUNCTION ORD(INPUTC(SENTRY:1))) <= (FUNCTION ORD('Z'))))
             IF ((FUNCTION ORD(INPUTC(SENTRY:1)) + CONVERTNUM) > (FUNCTION ORD('Z')))
                INSPECT INPUTC(SENTRY:1) REPLACING ALL INPUTC(SENTRY:1) BY RECHAR
             ELSE
                INSPECT INPUTC(SENTRY:1) REPLACING ALL INPUTC(SENTRY:1) BY RECHAR
             END-IF
          ELSE
                INSPECT INPUTC(SENTRY:1) REPLACING ALL INPUTC(SENTRY:1) BY INPUTC(SENTRY:1)
          END-IF

          COMPUTE SENTRY = SENTRY + 1
        --->  END-PERFORM
    DISPLAY INPUTC.
    COMPUTE LOOPI = LOOPI + 1
    --->END-PERFORM.
EXIT PROGRAM.
END PROGRAM SOLVE.
```

Comment: You have an IF with its ELSE having identical code. You also have an ELSE with an INSPECT replacing a character by itself. Why are you using INSPECT ... REPLACING for one-byte fields? Why not just MOVE? What is LOOPI for? Why not ADD 1 TO SENTRY instead of COMPUTE? You MULTIPLY -1, SUBTRACT ... FROM ZERO will be faster. But then you immediately set CIPHER to 0 in the PERFORM, so why negate anyway? I suspect there is more, but you've made the whole thing difficult to follow with FUNCTION upon FUNCTION.

Comment: Also, in `avcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz`, you may have meant `abc`...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

That nasty scope terminating period after `DISPLAY INPUTC.` is terminating the scope of the nested `PERFORM` statements. Get rid of the period and all should work fine.

The only periods you should ever use in the Procedure Division when coding a program to COBOL-85 standard are the ones required to terminate section and paragraph headers and another one to terminate the current paragraph, section or program.

Answer (score 4):

You have a period in the display INPUTC statement. Remove the period and you should be ok. The Period always ends a statement.